# Como faço para, quando o mouse sair de cima do botão ele volta ao tamanho normal com uma animação?

Tags: html, css, button, animação

```css
body button{
    background-color: #f80032;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    font-size: 40px;
    border-radius: 30px;

    transition-property: scale;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

body button:hover{
    transform: scale(1.1);
    width: 250;
    height: 150;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
        <div class="buy">
            <button>
                Comprar
            </button>
        </div>
```

Answer (score -3):

```
  <style>
   h1{
     width: 90px;
     height: 40px;
     background: pink;
     border: 1px solid black;
   }
    h1:hover{
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      background: linear-gradient(to left, purple, pink);
      transition: background 10s;
      transition: width 7s;
      transition: height 7s;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>
    Título
  </h1>
</body>
```

ESSE É UM EXEMPLO DE TRANSIÇÃO.
MAS BASICAMENTE VOCẼ DEVE USAR A TAG HOVER.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).